# What is this Sci-Fi time-travel Movie/TV Movie from the 1970's (I think) called?

Tags: story-identification, movie, time, androids

Does anybody know the title of a film that features robots or androids I think they were called and the humans, I think being chased by these androids, jumping through a time travel machine that speeds up and replays almost the whole film 2 or 3 times becoming faster each time.

It is a bit fuzzy as I was a child when it was shown on TV and this is all I can recall.

Comment: Time-travelling robots? @jackbnimble is the expert on these... http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2014/03/movies-with-time-traveling-robots/

Comment: I loved that movie and it was one of my first journeys in science fiction. It got me hooked and I think it was shown on Creature Double Feature on Channel 56 back in the 70's.

Comment: See OP confirmation comment for answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I think you may be talking about [The Time Travelers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Travelers_(1964_film)) from 1964. At the end they were being chased by mutants rather than robots, but they did show androids being built at an android factory earlier. What made me think of it was your comment "jumping through a time travel machine that speeds up and replays almost the whole film 2 or 3 times becoming faster each time". At the ending of The Time Travelers, they go back to a point just before their younger selves departed the lab through the time window, see their younger selves almost frozen in time, then jump through the time window again to an idyllic future. Then we see their younger selves repeating the events of the beginning of the film at normal speed, then everything speeds up and we see their younger selves repeat various scenes from throughout the film at high speed, including the ending part where they went back to the lab and saw their frozen younger selves, and the whole thing repeats an even faster loop until the film ends. Someone posted the ending online here:

Comment: wow that is amazing, thank you
almost certain that is the movie - looking for it now

thanks again